# One XIB View For Many Subclasses

Tags: swift, uiview, subclass, xib

I have one xib file with one view in it, connected to a UIView named `InputView`. I have a few subclasses of `InputView` such as `NameInput` and `DateInput`. I am using swift and I want to instantiate a `NameInput` object using the view in the xib file connected to `InputView`. I don't want to create more views in the xib file because each subclass of `InputView` appears the same. Essentially, I'm asking how I can use one xib file with one view with many subclasses of that view.

This should return a `DateInput` object.

```
class func make(label: String, placeholder: String, format: String) -> DateInput {

    let input = InputView.make() as DateInput

    input.label.text = label
    input.valueField.placeholder = placeholder
    input.format = format
    input.valueField.inputView = KeyboardView(subview: input.datePicker, appearance: .Dark)
    input.datePicker.addTarget(input, action: "setDate", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return input
}
```

And this should return a plain `InputView` object.

```
class func make() -> InputView {

    let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("InputView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as InputView

    view.valueField.delegate = view

    return view
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of doing this? Typically the view is strongly related to the class backing the view. What are you trying to achieve with the subclasses?

Comment: The subclasses all have the same view, but have different functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly and you're loading your `InputView` from a nib file, the answer is you can't.  The class of all objects loaded from the nib file is static in the nib file.

That said, it's not strictly true that you can't.  Since the nib file is loaded via `NSKeyedUnarchiver` you might be able to do something about registering your subclass as the loader for `InputView` and handle it that way, but it would be really ugly, convoluted, and illegible.

Best to just create multiple nib files that are identical other than the view class.

Comment: Okay. I suppose this will have to do for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to customize functionality using another mechanism.

For example, you can customize functionality in the view controller. The MVC design pattern typically involves customizing behavior in the controller, not in the view. So in the controller, you can customize your functionality based on the data that is loaded. You can do this in a variety of ways, including having custom context classes which are dynamically created by the controller, or supplying blocks to the controller to customize.

You can also customize functionality by passing in blocks to the view that do different things based on some context. I would do this if you need to customize view behaviors, such as autolayout constraints, etc.